# How to resize a virtual machine running ubuntu in VMware 5

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, vmware-vcenter

I was attempting to follow the instructions listed here

http://www.joomlaworks.net/blog/item/168-resizing-the-disk-space-on-ubuntu-server-vms-running-on-vmware-esxi-5

I started with a 150 gig Drive that is running LVM and as you can see from the screenshots when I try to do the fdisk I am getting "no free sectors available" 
[image: VMware]
<sub>(source: [zillabunny.com](http://www.zillabunny.com/resize/1.png))</sub>

[image: Ubuntu]
<sub>(source: [zillabunny.com](http://www.zillabunny.com/resize/2.png))</sub>

If possible I'd like to do this live as I would in windows (disk management, right click drive, extend[i understand this may not be possible]).

Can someone please assist me in this?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Here is what my GPARTED looks like, it says the extra 50 gigs I've added is unallocated and i'm still unable to resize my drive

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you found a workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to get the disk geometry to be re-read, you can try the `partprobe` CLI command or [rescanning your SCSI bus](https://blogs.it.ox.ac.uk/oxcloud/2013/03/25/rescanning-your-scsi-bus-to-see-new-storage/). Failing that, you will need to reboot the VM.

This will find your SCSI bus number, in my example, it's 2:

```
cwatson@odin:~$ grep mpt /sys/class/scsi_host/host?/proc_name
/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/proc_name:mptspi
```

Then rescan your bus using this command:

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/scan
```

---

Another way to rescan your SCSI bus is by running this command:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/0\:0\:0\:0/device/rescan
```

Note that the colons in the path are preceded with back-slashes. You can find your device ID by running this (you may have more than once SCSI device):

```
ls -l ls /sys/class/scsi_device
```

---

**Update:** As per your GParted screenshot, you'll need to unmount the LVM partition from within GParted, then resize the *extended* partition to take up the extra space, and then create a new partition within that extended partition, and use LVM to span your volume across both partitions (outside the scope of this answer).

Comment: # grep mpt /sys/class/scsi_host/host?/proc_name
/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/proc_name:mptspi
# echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/scan

Comment: `# fdisk /dev/sda

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 187.9 GB, 187904819200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 22844 cylinders, total 367001600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00026739

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   314570751   157034497    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   314570751   157034496   8e  Linux LVM
`

Comment: Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (1 primary, 1 extended, 2 free)
   l   logical (numbered from 5)
Select (default p): l
Adding logical partition 6
No free sectors available

Comment: would appear that I am getting the same result.   even after scanning the scsi bus.

Comment: I am going to just restart this and see if it makes any difference

Comment: @zillabunny I've just added one more way to rescan the SCSI bus in my answer.

Comment: even after a reboot I'm still getting No free sectors available

Comment: interestingly enough when I do a fdisk -l I am now seeing the increase in space on /dev/sda

Comment: It looks like there is a utility called GParted on the desktop version if I do a apt-get install xinit will I be able to use this?

Comment: Apprently I will have to boot into a liveCD to do this. I'll report back shortly.

Comment: I've updated the original ticket with what my GParted looks like

Comment: @zillabunny just updated my answer.

Comment: i'm using the liveCD, nothing is mounted not sure why I have those locks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and succeed using `cfdisk` utility instead.